# Datepicker in vuetify with validators

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I need to create a new component that only have a datepicker with his validators. This component is generic because I need to use in more components easily. I need that when you click into the datepicker and you don't pick any date show a red validation like this:

[image]

and then:

[image]

If you pick any date, this validation should disappear.

I had thinked in this form:

```
<ValidationObserver v-slot="{ handleSubmit, invalid }" ref="form">
<v-form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(submit)">

    <ValidationProvider ref="form" :name="nombre" :rules="rules" v-slot="{ errors }">
        <v-menu v-model="dialogOpen" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition"
            offset-y min-width="auto">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-text-field :error-messages="errors" v-model="value" :label="label" prepend-icon="mdi-calendar" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                </v-text-field>
            </template>
            <v-date-picker required v-model="value" @input="dialogOpen = false" @change="changed"
                @keydown="checkValidate"></v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
    </ValidationProvider>

</v-form>
```

But this doesn't work. Someone can share me another example or solution for this thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that vee-validate (v3) uses `v-model` to find the input tags, and since `vuetify` uses `v-model` for various components to compose them together like the date-picker, vee-validate will validate the `menu` instead of the `v-text-field`.

There is a workaround, you need to wrap the Vuetify's picker snippet in a new component `DatePicker.vue`

```html
<v-menu v-model="dialogOpen" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="auto">
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-text-field :error-messages="errors" v-model="value" :label="label" prepend-icon="mdi-calendar" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
    </v-text-field>
</template>
  <v-date-picker required v-model="value" @input="dialogOpen = false" @change="changed" @keydown="checkValidate"></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

Note that you still need to implement `v-model` support for this new component by emitting `input` event when value changes.

And then use the custom `DatePicker` with the `ValidationProvider`:

```html
<ValidationProvider ref="form" :name="nombre" :rules="rules" v-slot="{ errors }">
  <DatePicker v-model="value" />
</ValidationProvider>
```

Of course that was a shortsight on vee-validate's part, and the new `v4` release for Vue 3 avoids this bad design.